# How do I centre an image in a browser window with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image sitting in a div that I want to centre in a browser window using CSS. I don't want to change the HTML unless I have to, which will involve changes to several hundred webpages.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="main-header">
<img src="images/main-header.png" alt="STN Yacht Charters" class="fancy scalable" >
</div>
```

And I've tried this amongst other things for the CSS without success.

```
#main-header {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Grateful for any and all help as always

Comment: first entry googling it *To center an image using text-align: center you must place the <img> inside of a block-level element such as a div. 
Since the text-align property only applies to block-level elements, you place text-align: center; on the wrapping block-level element to achieve a horizontally centered <img> .30.12.2019*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You are using an incorrect CSS selector

## Solution

```
.main-header {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  text-align: center; /* not required */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to your `.main-header` in your CSS:

```
.main-header {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: he is using an incorrect selector

Comment: `text-align: center` declaration is not required

Comment: @kantbtrue why did you add it to your answer then too??

Comment: added a comment for it, thanks!

Comment: That has worked! Stackoverflow recommend I don't say thank you. So I won't but I do owe you a beer guys

Comment: @Ken you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer.